# Issue with retrieving last id inserted

Tags: sql, sql-server, odbc

I use `odbc_connection` , the issue is I need to get the last id inserted.

I use this query here but I don't get the required result:

```
echo  $result = odbc_exec($connection, "SELECT @"."@IDENTITY AS Ident");
```

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: @pyetjegoo before calling `IDENTITY` have you did any insert, if so then post that query too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use IDENT_CURRENT(‘dtabase name’) to retrieve the last identity value inserted into column from any connection.

The reason your solution doesn’t work is that @@Identity works only on current connection and disregards other connections.

Answer (score 0):

If you have MySQL under ODBC - you can use the next query:

```
"SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID( );"
```

or

```
SELECT @@IDENTITY AS ID
```

Comment: Yes well, i tried all this but it didn't work.. aparently i don't have it.. because i'm connecting to a sql server..

Comment: Curious... $result = odbc_exec($conn, "SELECT @"."@IDENTITY AS Ident"); must work.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the table you are inserting to has an Identity column?

When you say your not getting the required result do you mean you are getting the wrong number or are you getting null?  If you are getting the wrong number does the table you are inserting to have a trigger that inserts to another table?

Comment: I've just noticed your comment that its returning the wrong number, try scope_identity() as marc_s suggests.